# Android how to deduct money

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have an app idea, but one of necessary condition is it's ability to take away money from user's account.

Initially user would have to agree to terms and conditions and allow app to deduct certain amount of money (different every time) at daily basis.

Is this possible with in app purchase?
If not, how?

Comment: I believe in-app purchases must be authorized via user interaction, and cannot achieve automatic billing with different amounts. Instead I'd suggest you use a payment provider where users register their cards, and you charge the users from there.

Comment: I am not going to download your app..:p

Comment: @Daniel I am not sure, but charging directly from bank accounts might violate Google developer policy.

Comment: How about keeping user promo money kind of thing. that is most custom way for you. if user has a wallet for your app only. you can do whatever operations you want.

Comment: I'd never accept such an agreement.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to withdraw different amount of money, but instead you can withdraw fixed amount via in-app subscriptions. Also, it is not working on daily basis, but rather weekly, monthly or yearly. Refer to official documentation for more details.